# FTP Upload Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ftp

I need a FTP Upload plugin for Eclipse. I don't wanna use Aptana since it doesn't work on PHP Development version of Eclipse and the perspective didn't work well so I am looking for such a plugin or something works like DispatchAsp for Visual Studio. Like syncing, remote view, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to/can't use Aptana you could take a look at **RSE**

http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#What_is_the_Target_Management_Project.3F

Comment: Can you give me a download link for RSE because I searched it and TM comes up which doesn't look what I quite want. Thanks.

Comment: Think the links in this post are still valid: http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/